# Apply CSS to special characters on page

Tags: html, css, asp.net

We are currently trying to improve the visibility of the required fields on a form on our internal self service portal. However, the backend of the system does not add the required tag or add an asterisk "*" to the field so we cannot style it in CSS. We do however, manually add an asterisk to the name of the field which is displayed in a span like so:

`<span id="ctl00_content_genTextBoxLbl0">*Forename:</span>`

Is there any way in CSS I can style all the asterisks on the page to improve the font size/colour?

Thanks,

Comment: CSS is for styling, not text manipulation

Answer (score 1):

I usually replace a phrase and encapsule it in a span tag with a class name that does whatever you want

```
replace("Phrase", "<span class=\"highlight\">Phrase</span>")
```

Comment: How would I use the replace function?

Comment: @Browno what language are you working with?

Comment: C# , aspx pages

Comment: @Browno you run the replace in the controllers that generate content before it's written to the page. did that make sense? maybe you could paste some c# code from a controller or page behind. basically the syntax is string.replace("", "")

Comment: I think the problem is the forms are generated on the fly, so I can't specifically replace the * as each field has a different ID. Hence why I wanted to try and change it was CSS across the whole page

Comment: @Browno you can also use JavaScript to do this, that might be simpler. the syntax is the same

Comment: Would that replace just the asterisks on the page though? I don't want to replace them, just increase their font size/colour.

Comment: @Browno something like this: var tag = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
tag.innerHtml = tag.innerHtml.replace("*", "<span class=\"YourClass\">*</span>;. save it in a js file and include it on your site

Comment: @Browno yes. you only search and replaces * with <span class="YourClass">*</span>

Comment: I have added the below  `<script>
 function replaceasterisks () {
 var tag = document.getElementsByTagName("span"); tag.innerHtml = tag.innerHtml.replace("*", "<h2>*</h2>;
 }
 </script>` and even tried it in the same format as yours, then styling the span class and it doesn't change them at all

Comment: @Browno I made a js fiddle, check out https://jsfiddle.net/SteinTheRuler/43gys6dv/25/